# Create multiple unique barcodes in a loop using JSBarcode

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am creating a table of barcodes using `JSBarcode` and a for-each loop. The problem is that the value of the barcodes are always the same (for some reason they are all the value of the last element in the loop).

Here is my code:

```
<tbody>
<% lineitemObj.forEach(function(obj) { %>
   <tr>
      <td><%= obj.id %></td>
      <td><%= obj.drawing_num %></td>
      <td><%= obj.description %></td>
      <td><%= obj.qty %></td>
      <td>
         <svg id="barcode"></svg>
         <script>
            var ln = '<%= obj.id %>'
            JsBarcode("#barcode", ln);
          </script> 
       </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

How do I get the barcodes to properly represent the unique id of each object?

Comment: um, ids are unique.... can't have more than one element with the same id.....

Comment: @epascarello Yes I know but for some reason the barcodes are not being created properly, all of them have the same value and I'm not sure why

Comment: Well fix the id problem so you can select each one.... 10 guys named BOB, you yell BOB, what happens? How is it supposed to mean BOB #4?

Comment: Again, all the IDS are the same `id="barcode"` HOW is the code supposed to know what barcode it is meant to update when they are ALL THE SAME?

Comment: @epascarello Oh lol, is there anyway to dynamically change the id of the barcode element each time?

Comment: forEach gives you the index....

Answer (score 0):

Try it

JsBarcode("#barcode", "12345", {format: "pharmacode"});

Comment: add dynamic value here  "12345"